# Encoding issues when exporting as CSV

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I have this code to export a filtered html table. I have two issues with it which I can't figure out:
1) I get "â€¢" instead of a bullet point • in my exported .csv file. I've tried changing charset from UTF-8 to iso-8859 in meta head and this script but this didn't help.
2) When I have quotes in the sentence it treats it as a comma and breaks the sentence, putting it into a next cell. Example:
**I am a "good" man with a good reputation** 
would be broken into something like:
A1 I am a "good" man with 
B1 good reputation

I can't work it out why this happens?
Thanks!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

        $(function(){

            $('#downloadButton').click(function () {
        var keepOnlyA1= true                        // put this true to remove unused numeric A0 field from each row   [ A0, A1=[field,field,...]]
                                            //
            var a= tf_table1.GetFilteredData(true)              // a=  [  [A0,A1=[field,field,...]], [A0,A1=[field,field,...]], ...[..,[...]] ]
                                            //        ^a[0]                      ^a[1]                         ^a[n]
            for (var i=0,row,r1; i<a.length; i++){              //
                row=  a[i]                      //  row=  [A0, A1=[field,field,...]]
                r1= row[1]                      //                ^r1
                for (var j=0; j<r1.length; j++){            // surround each field with quotes "field"
                     r1[j]= '"'+r1[j].replace('"','""')+'"'     // if there is any " already inside field string, it needs to be doubled.  per csv rfc.
                }                           //
                if (keepOnlyA1) a[i]= r1                // if true, just replace each row array with its single interior A1=[field,field,...] array
            }                               //
            var colvals = a.join("\r\n") +"\r\n"                //

                var blob = new Blob([ colvals ], {type: 'text/csv;charset=ISO-8859;'});
                //var filename = $('#fileName').val();

                if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "S7_Won_Tendes_Export_Filtered.csv"); 
                }
                else {
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.download = filename;
                    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        a.style.display= "none"             //added//  invisible
                        document.body.appendChild(a)            //added//  firefox wouldn't click() it without being appended
                    a.click();
                    //if (a.remove) a.remove();
                        a.parentNode.removeChild(a)         //added//
                }
            });
        });//]]>  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I managed to find answers:

Replace

```
var blob = new Blob([ colvals ],
```

with

```
var blob = new Blob(["\uFEFF" + buffer],
```

and

```
r1[j]= '"'+r1[j].replace('"','""')+'"'
```

with

```
r1[j]= '"'+r1[j].replace(/"/g, '""')+'"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!